# How to get full post body using symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, soap

I am a newbie on SOAP fields and things and do not quite know how everything works properly, but I get a notification from eBay which contains soap message in post body. Usually a post message seems like:

```
{'id':300}
```

And so we can get it in by name using for example `$_POST['id']`. SOAP message is posted as one string like this:

```
<?xml...
```

Using plain php I would do `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

So, my question is simple: how can I get this message using Symfony? Or should I just do `file_get_contents('php://input')`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and lacks details, and what you have done so far. Please consider updating it and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Request` object to get content and then you can use [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) to traverse the nodes and find content.

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

...

public function apiAction(Request $request)
{
    $xmlContent = $request->getContent();
    $crawler = new Crawler($xmlContent);

    $text = $crawler
        ->filter('node > childnode')
        ->text();
}
```

Comment: Good luck json_decoding XML!

Comment: @Oldskool, He noted that post body seems like `{'id':300}`, it's json format

Comment: No, OP stated that a post message *usually* looks like that, but that he/she now gets a SOAP message, which is XML.

Comment: @Oldskool yes you're right, I misunderstood the question and just quickly scanned it and found json line, my bad. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, this is better. -1 converted to +1.

Comment: @DanMironis I appreciate your quick answer. Will test it.